# Definition of a Hilbert basis

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, definition

Given a Hilbert space $\cal H$, what criterion describes the property "$\cal B$ is a Hilbert basis for $\cal H$"? It would be even better if the definition can be stated in a way that mimics some characterization of a vector space basis.

For example, if we consider the spanning set part of the definition, we have

- A vector space basis satisfies ${\rm span}({\cal B})=V$,

which has the analogue

- A Hilbert space basis satisfies $\overline{{\rm span}({\cal B})}=\cal H$.

What are the analogues of vector sum characterizations? Or linear independence?

Comment: Note: the two notions of basis that you are referring to are referred to as *Hamel bases* and *Schauder bases* (respectively).  In the context of Hilbert spaces (and more generally in Banach spaces), "basis" is often synonymous with "Schauder basis".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for the terminology, haven't heard of a Schauder basis before. One thing which bothers me about the definition of Schauder basis is that the basis set is required to be ordered or countable, so that conditionally convergent series can be considered; I was rather imagining that the series be absolutely convergent and taken over arbitrarily large sets (uncountable Hilbert bases also being permissible here), using say the filter of finite subsets under reverse inclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Hilbert space, one typically uses a orthonormal basis, that is a system of vectors $\{x_n\}$, with $$(x_i, x_j) = \delta_{ij}$$
and
$$\overline{\mathrm{span}(\{x_n\}) } = \mathcal{H}.$$

Comment: Is the orthonormality condition sufficient to ensure linear independence even if we are taking limits?

Comment: What do you mean precisely?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro it is sufficient: note that if $y_i$ are orthogonal, then 
$$
\left\|\sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i \right\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \|y_i\|^2
$$
so, the left side can only be zero if all $y_i$ are zero.